# My Div does not React to Position: Absolute With The Container Div set to Position: Relative

Tags: html, css

This should be fairly simple, however I am stumped as to why it is not working. The div (logo-and-text) inside the container (logo-wrapper) does not want to work with position absolute and the parent as position relative. If I do the individual image inside the div or the text it works.

I've tried setting the height of the container, setting margins to zero, checked in chrome dev tools.

```
<section id="contact-me-section">
        <div id="contact-me-section-wrapper">
            <div id="have-a-question-wrapper">
                <h2 class="contact-h2">HAVE A QUESTION?</h2>
                <div class="connect-with-me-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="contact-img" src="images/location.png" alt="">
                    <p class="contact-p">Dayton, Ohio</p>
                </div>
                <div class="connect-with-me-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="contact-img" src="images/phone.png" alt="">
                    <p class="contact-p">( 937 ) 336-9359</p>
                </div>
                <div class="connect-with-me-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="contact-img" src="images/email.png" alt="">
                    <p class="contact-p">contact@ryanjthacker.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="logo-wrapper">
                <div id="logo-and-text">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
                    <p>Copyright © 2019 Ryan Thacker - All rights reserved</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="connect-with-me-wrapper">
                <h2 class="contact-h2">CONNECT WITH ME</h2>
                <div class="connect-with-me-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="contact-img" src="images/facebook_white.png" alt="">
                    <p class="contact-p">Facebook</p>
                </div>
                <div class="connect-with-me-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="contact-img" src="images/linkedin_white.png" alt="">
                    <p class="contact-p">LinkedIn</p>
                </div>
                <div class="connect-with-me-image-wrapper">
                    <img class="contact-img" src="images/github_white.png" alt="">
                    <p class="contact-p">GitHub</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
#contact-me-section {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
}

#contact-me-section-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#have-a-question-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

#logo-wrapper {
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo-and-text {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#logo-wrapper img {
    width: 116px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#connect-with-me-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.contact-h2 {
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: left;
}

.contact-p {
    color: #989898;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.contact-img {
    width: 60px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.connect-with-me-image-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: What 'container' are you talking about here?

Comment: Good point, I've updated the question!

Comment: Thank you, and what are you expecting to see? just the text and image?

Comment: I am trying to align the div logo-and-text to the bottom of the parent div logo-wrapper, however it acts like it doesn't exist, and does not make any changes. However if instead of using logo-and-text I use the img or p inside of it with the parent logo-wrapper it works, but then I have the issue of them overlapping each other because they are taken out of the flow of the document.

Comment: There is no container in your html code or css. may you please specify the container you talking about?

Comment: The div with the id="logo-wrapper" is the container for the div with the id="logo-and-text"

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved it, its due to using flex box. The solution is a much easier and flexible way to do it.

Instead I just used align-self: flex-end; to the container.